# Does drupal "views infinite scroll" module work with "image matrix" module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I've installed the two modules (views infinite scroll & image matrix) on Drupal 7 hoping to have them work together on a view. The infinite scroll works with all view format types except "Image Matrix".  The image matrix module works with all view pager types except the "infinite scroll" type. When I set the two together on a view, the images appear in the proper matrix layout but the inifinite scroll does not work.

Has anyone gotten a view to work with an "image matrix" format and an "infinite scroll" pager type on Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1488678) for imagematrix module: "*Views Infinite Scroll does not handle non-standard view styles*". But

That means that by default the 2 modules does not work together.